# Flutter: how to place forgot password button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

`

```
      child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          _EmailInput(),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          _ForgotPasswordButton()
        ],
      ),
```

`With the given setup what should I do to place **forgot password button** at the bottom of the page eg: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iyqy8u4gwWXaRj6SLey3qzgvdICDor2Z/view?usp=sharing

I tried wrapping them in a Container and Column but it doesn't work

Comment: I would recommend changing your question title to "how to place a widget at the bottom of a screen" so other users with a similar problem would be able to find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you widgets in a Column and wrap your _EmailInput() in an Expanded(). That will make your _EmailInput() expand to fill the available space along the main axis and push the _ForgetPasswordButton() to the bottom

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: _EmailInput(),
      )
    ),
    _ForgotPasswordButton()
  ],
)
```

Comment: Hello Dung it says error it redirects me to page flex.dart on this ff line 
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    assert(_debugHasNecessaryDirections);
    final BoxConstraints constraints = this.constraints;
    assert(() {
      final FlutterError? constraintsError = _debugCheckConstraints(
        constraints: constraints,
        reportParentConstraints: true,
      );
      if (constraintsError != null) {
        throw constraintsError;
      }
      return true;
    }())

Comment: @DanylMarie can you add the code on how you apply my answer?

Comment: `        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Center(
              child: _EmailInput(),
            )),
            _ForgotPasswordButton()
          ],
        ));`

Comment: I couldn't seem to add the full code but this is how it looks like [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vh7bg_c5AjQ_D3AwbU4prh3m-lDIB-OJ/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: When I tried to run it -it redirects me to this 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TxHhCGxPbgprmmSnS23bmzyhx_TnojIW/view?usp=share_link]

Comment: @DanylMarie I created a pen, check it out: https://codepen.io/dungngo/pen/LYrpXyR

Comment: It helps! Wow thanks, I just made an alter because my body is in a separate page Thank you Dung Ngo!